# How does an azure app service access a no azure web server

Tags: azure

I have an Azure app service and in some cases I need to send a web request to a non-azure webserver. What do I need to do to make it possible.
Currently the web request fails with no clear error message.

In response to a HttpClient Put request I get a System.Net.WebException exception which says there were errors.

THe same request works from a desktop application.

Comment: Where is this server located? Publicly available or internal to Azure? Is it pingable?

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is reachable from the internet you should be able to access it through your App Service. Try to log a ping to your webserver and google (8.8.8.8).

If your App Service is in a VNET you should enable some outbound rules to your webservers IP adress.

Comment: The web server is reachable from the internet and as I said the same code works fine from a desktop application on Windows which is why I thought the issue was an Azure restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The server I am connecting to is an other Azure service. After some more investigating, It appears that I can connect to it if I do not use SSL (i.e. http://) but the connection is immediately closed when using SSL (https://). I assume that the problem must be related to the use of SSL.